# Grunt Karma PhantomJS - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'?

Tags: angularjs, testing, gruntjs, karma-jasmine

I keep getting an error when running this in my terminal (at the location of gruntfile.js):

```
grunt karma
```

The solutions here either didn't work or are no longer an option - https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing/issues/2

Here is the output:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
26 05 2017 13:43:15.838:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:8082/
26 05 2017 13:43:15.840:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
26 05 2017 13:43:15.848:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
26 05 2017 13:43:15.955:ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]: Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag

26 05 2017 13:43:16.130:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 9TxdacwF4rc7mUB0AAAA with id 76282796

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
at app/client/app.js:2


PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
at app/client/paths/home/homeCtrl.js:2
```

Here is my code:

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/**/*.js'
    ],

    port: 8082,

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins: [
       'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
       'karma-jasmine',
       'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
    ],

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
})};
```

grunt test block for karma in gruntfile.js

```
karma: {
    unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.config.js',
        singleRun: true
    }
}
```

homeCtrl.spec.js

```
describe('HomeCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var HomeCtrl;
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller){ 
        HomeCtrl = $controller('HomeCtrl');
    }));

    describe('message', function() {
        it('should read hello', function() {
            expect(HomeCtrl.message).toBe('hello');
        });
    });
```

});

homeCtrl.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('HomeCtrl', ($scope) => {
        $scope.message = 'hello';    
    })
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial'])
    .config(($routeProvider) => { 
        $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl : "paths/home/home.html" });
    });
```

Here is the folder structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncQI3.png

Any input would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You missed comma here `port: 8082`

Comment: oh yes thanks, however the problem still persists. Just an error copying the code over.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
at app/client/app.js:2` can you show your app.js please?

Comment: angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial'])
.config(($routeProvider) => {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "paths/home/home.html"
    });
});

Comment: You have any ideas?

Comment: it suggests a potential issue that when `app.js` is being served, a html (most likely error like 404) is returned instead - but i'm not sure this should ever happen in a karma context

Comment: nope... problem is with the browser not being able to run ES6 code - the `=>` part is the problem... you most likely need polyfills for phantomjs - see  [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-es6-shim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this issue is caused by PhantomJS not being able to run ES6 code.

The part that's causing this is the arrow function in `app.js`: `.config(($routeProvider) => {`

So either

1. **Use ES5 valid code**

   ```
   .config(function($routeProvider) {
   ```
2. **Provide the appropriate polyfills**, e.g, using [`karma-es6-shim`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-es6-shim)
3. **Pre-compile your code**, e.g. using [`grunt-babel`](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorted, thank you. Kinda a shame how PhantomJS isn't using ES6 yet without additional support. I assumed it was an issue with my html code.